# Android using MediaExtractor and MediaCodec from a socket (streaming mpeg)

Tags: android, sockets

i have the following code which decodes an mp4 from the sdcard and displays it just fine (mostly not my code, i found it here https://github.com/vecio but added the socket stuff)

```
package io.vec.demo.mediacodec;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class DecodeActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);
        sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setContentView(sv);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayer = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.interrupt();
        }
    }

    private class PlayerThread extends Thread {
        private MediaExtractor extractor;
        private MediaCodec decoder;
        private Surface surface;

        public PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ServerSocket serverSocket;

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(21121);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(clientSocket);
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();

                extractor = new MediaExtractor();
                final String fname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/out.mp4";
                try {
                    //extractor.setDataSource(fname); // THIS WORKS
                    extractor.setDataSource(fd);      // THIS DOESN'T
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                    MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                    if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                        extractor.selectTrack(i);
                        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                        decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (decoder == null) {
                    Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
                    return;
                }

                decoder.start();

                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                boolean isEOS = false;
                long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    if (!isEOS) {
                        int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                        if (inIndex >= 0) {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                            int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                            Log.d("DecodeActivity", "sampleSize="+sampleSize);
                            if (sampleSize < 0) {
                                // We shouldn't stop the playback at this point, just pass the EOS
                                // flag to decoder, we will get it again from the
                                // dequeueOutputBuffer
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                isEOS = true;
                            } else {
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                                extractor.advance();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
                    switch (outIndex) {
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                        outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                        //Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

                        // We use a very simple clock to keep the video FPS, or the video
                        // playback will be too fast
                        while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                            try {
                                sleep(10);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                        break;
                    }

                    // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
                    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                decoder.stop();
                decoder.release();
                extractor.release();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When i try use the fd i get from the socket instead of the file name, i get a runtime error with a lot of massages about "seek to 0 failed" "seek to 4 failed" etc. Not surprising since you can't seek on a socket. (note that i have a simple client on the PC feeding the same test file via a socket)

But this leaves me with a major problem, how to fix this?

I thought about removing MediaExtractor altogether and filling the buffer inputBuffers manually from the data stream but the problem is, MediaExtractor does a lot more than simply read bytes from a file, it does a lot of parsing of the data stream so it can pass the right thing to decoder.queueInputBuffer.

I notice i'm not the only one with this problem
[How to set up Streaming audio with MediaExtractor and MediaCodec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532511/how-to-set-up-streaming-audio-with-mediaextractor-and-mediacodec)
but no solutions to be found.

This is very frustrating, you would thing there should be a way to stream video to android over a socket without http

Maybe i just need to put a http server in my pc ap?

Comment: You should use UDP instead of TCP when streaming media http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html

Comment: thanks, do you think it would read from a datagram socket? sounds less likely to me

Comment: Hi @steveh, I'm currently working on a similar application. Did you get a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?